# Transfer folder in socket - java

Tags: java, sockets, stream, zip

My goal is to transfer a folder via `Socket` with the following process:

1. Zip a folder.
2. Transfer it from client to server using `Socket`.
3. Have the server extract the zip file.

It is working on the client side, but on the server side the zip file is received but not extracted. If I manually copy the zip file to the server, it is extracted successfully.

What could be causing the zip file to be received but not extracted? I think the problem is on the transferring process.

Here is the client side code :

```
new ZipUtils("Folder.zip","Folder").zip();

try {
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3232);

    final File myFile= new File("Folder.zip");
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024*8];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    OutputStream os;
    try{
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
        dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
        int read;
        while((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1){
            dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    dis.close();
    socket.close();
}catch (IOException e){}
```

And here is the server side code:

```
private static Socket socket;
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static BufferedInputStream bis;
private static DataInputStream dis;
private static DataOutputStream dos;
private static String RootDir = "D:/Devdroid/";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3232);
        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            String fileName = null;
            InputStream in;
            int bufferSize=0;
            try {
                bufferSize=socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
                in=socket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
                fileName = RootDir+clientData.readUTF();
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int read;
                while((read = clientData.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                output.close();
            }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}


            new ZipUtils(fileName,RootDir).unzip();


            dis.close();
            dos.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

And here is the `ZipUtil.java` file:

```
public class ZipUtils {
    private String _zip;
    private String _path;

    public ZipUtils(String zip, String path) {
        _zip = zip;
        _path = path;
    }

    public void unzip() {
        dirChecker("");
        try  {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zip);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                    dirChecker(ze.getName());
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_path + ze.getName());
                    BufferedOutputStream bufout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        bufout.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    zin.closeEntry();
                    bufout.close();
                    fout.close();
                }
            }
            zin.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    private void dirChecker(String dir) {
        File f = new File(_path + dir);
        if(!f.isDirectory()) {f.mkdirs();}
    }

    public void zip(){
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(_zip);          
            ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            File fileToZip = new File(_path);
            try{
                zipFile(fileToZip, fileToZip.getName(), zipOut);
                zipOut.close();
                fos.close();
            }catch(IOException e){}
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
    }
    private void zipFile(File fileToZip, String fileName, ZipOutputStream zipOut) throws IOException {
        if (fileToZip.isHidden()) {
            return;
        }
        if (fileToZip.isDirectory()) {
            if (fileName.endsWith("/")) {
                zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
                zipOut.closeEntry();
            } else {
                zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName + "/"));
                zipOut.closeEntry();
            }
            File[] children = fileToZip.listFiles();
            for (File childFile : children) {
                zipFile(childFile, fileName + "/" + childFile.getName(), zipOut);
            }
            return;
        }
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        fis.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: The client side is doing `dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);` (why are you sending the *buffer size?*), but the server is not reading that long value.  I would remove that line altogether.

Comment: yeah i will remove that but i dont think its fix the problem.